# Gearman Not Listening on Right IP For Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gearman

I have compiled Gearman on my ubuntu machine and it works fine in localhost mode but I get a connection error when connecting from another machine to add a new job to the queue.

I have tried...

1. Editing the config file located at `/etc/default/gearman-job-server` to add `--listen={ip-here}` and that did nothing.
2. Editing the upstart script directly to add the `--listen` flag and that did nothing either.
3. Editing the `/etc/init.d/gearman-job-server` file to add the `--listen` and `--port` paramaters to the start script.
4. Manually editing the upstart file at `/etc/init/gearman-job-server.conf` and commenting out the existing exec line and adding in the following lines after the `respawn` command...

`script`

`exec gearmand --listen={ip} --port=4703`

`end script`

The only way I have Gearman working at the moment is by manually running the command `gearmand -d -listen={ip} --port=4703` which has made it work. Now I understand that the `-d` flag launches it in daemon mode which has allowed me to close the SSH session while still keeping it running but any machine reboot is going to put me right back where I started.

I want to have Gearman automatically start on boot, or restart through the `sudo service` command listening to the correct IP and port and I don't want to have to log into the server every time something goes wrong to manually start the daemon again.

I have been through serverFault which led me to the first two options but still needing help as neither of those worked.

Comment: Would you be willing to post your  htop  results from the server hosting gearman?  We need to compare ours to another installation.  We are successfully using addserver and running.  Wondering why we never have a dropserver in our application.  Any example you could share of dropserver, or a url with an explanation of dropserver function.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this figured by digging right into the Debian bug reports...

Even though Gearman has the config file located in `/etc/default/gearman-job-server` and even though it has entries in the `/etc/init/` and `/etc/init.d/` directories these are apparently ignored in many installations (Possible from the point that the `init.d` command for service control was superceeded by the `service` command but basically what you need to do it...

1. Navigate to the `/lib/systemd/system` directory and open `gearman-job-server.service` in your chosen text editor.
2. Update the `ExecStart` command. At this point you can either manually code in the parameters you want or you can include the default params environment variable by adding `$PARAMS` to the end of the line. The parameters you care about are the `--listen` and `--port` parameters. The listen parameter should be the publicly accessible IP of your server.
3. Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
4. Run `sudo service gearman-job-server restart`
5. Give it a test and it should be working now

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS 7 there is the same problem.
You may edit the /etc/sysconfig/gearmand and add the following:

```
OPTIONS="--listen=127.0.0.1 --port=4730"
```

Note, the default port is 4730, not 4703.
Then, run "sudo service gearmand restart" -- and get "gearadmin --status" working!